# Is Apple ID required?

Tags: ios, ios-appstore, apple-id

I just got my first iPhone 6. I wonder if it is a requirement to get an Apple ID or if it is **possible to install apps without having an Apple ID**? I think that I already have so many IDs and I don't want a new.

Comment: You don't need to get a new ID every time, but you do need **one** at least. Pick an existing one that's bought the most things, as they're not transferrable. Forget the others; managing multiple IDs is a nightmare.

Comment: Ah.. I re-read. You have many IDs, but not yet an Apple ID? Then yes, you need one. That's how Apple knows you are you. Anything you buy or download belongs to your ID, not to the device it's on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you need to use an Apple ID in order to download/buy apps/music/movies/books.

Apple assigns all transaction like downloaded apps (even "buying" a free app) to your account so you can download them later. One Apple ID is all you need in order to move freely in Apple's ecosystem.

Whenever you sign in on a new iPhone with your Apple ID your previous downloads will be available without the need to buy them again. The same is true for purchased music/movies/books/ringtones etc.

As noted by @SteveChambers you can use your current email address as your Apple ID.

Comment: Note you do *not* have to have an iCloud address, you can use your current preferred email address as your AppleID.

Comment: You get given an iCloud address anyway. I've got the set, mac.com, me.com & icloud.com - all handed to me as each new system came out; yet my main address is still my own regular domain address.